# Unable to Populate DropDownList using Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am attempting to populate a DropDownList using Ajax. My code is below. I've stepped through all of the code and everything is working without any obvious C# or Jquery errors. On button click the Jquery runs and calls my WebMethod. The GetLanguageList breakpoint is hit in my C# code and the list of 6 objects is returned successfully. The success function iterates through each of the 6 objects. However, the drop down list remains empty. I am not using update panels.

I've tried changing the return type to Array and List of ListItem. I've tried using an AjaxControlToolkit ComboBox instead of a DropDownList. I've tried just having the DropDownList to populate on documentready rather than on  button click. I trued adding Text and Value to the DataText and DataValue properties for the DropDownList.

What else could be causing the DropDownList not to populate?

My Method

```
    [WebMethod()]
    public static ArrayList GetLanguageList()
    {
        ArrayList lstArrLanguage = new ArrayList();
        lstArrLanguage.Add(new ListItem("C#", "C#"));
        lstArrLanguage.Add(new ListItem("Java", "Java"));
        lstArrLanguage.Add(new ListItem("PHP", "PHP"));
        lstArrLanguage.Add(new ListItem("VB.NET", "VB.NET"));
        lstArrLanguage.Add(new ListItem("JavaScript", "JavaScript"));
        lstArrLanguage.Add(new ListItem("jQuery", "jQuery"));
        return lstArrLanguage;
    }
```

My Jquery

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

         $(function() {
            $("#locationList").change(function () {
                TestMethod();
            }).change();
        });

        function TestMethod() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<%= ResolveUrl("EmailEditor.aspx/GetLanguageList") %>',
                data: '',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#DropDownList1").empty().append($("<option></option>").val("[-]").html("Please select"));
                    $.each(msg.d, function() {
                        $("#DropDownList1").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);                      
                }
            });
        };
    </script> 
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="TestMethod()" runat="server" Text="Button" />
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
```

Comment: can you verify that the ID of the asp DropDownList control is in fact "DropDownList1" when the page renders ?  In my experience, the asp control renders with an id similar to, but not exactly the same as the id you assign.  you may need to use $('[id*="DropDownList1"]') to target the element.

Comment: Use `$('#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>')` to Refer the Dropdown ID. And When you are invoking the WebMethod and use breakpoint at code behind, it is stoping here???

Comment: You should consider refactoring your $.ajax call to use promises instead of the configuration parameters. See the documentation for usage examples.

From jQuery's website: Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead. Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @JacobHeater I will look into it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the success function to the following:

```
success: function(msg) {
    $("#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>").empty().append($("<option></option>").val("[-]").html("Please select"));
    $.each(msg.d, function() {
       $("#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I must be going crazy to have missed that.